# Comment code using elisp

Tags: comment

Input and desired output

```
Original code                       Commented out code:                  
C %% MODULE %% module_name           C~ CPR C ## MODULE ## module_name    
lines of code                        C~ CPR lines of code                 
lines of code                        C~ CPR lines of code                 
.....                                C~ CPR .....                         
.....                                C~ CPR .....                         
.....                                C~ CPR ....                          
....                                 C~ CPR ....
....                                 C~ CPR ....
C %% END MODULE %% module_name       C~ CPR C ## END MODULE ## module_name
```

Steps:

1. The cursor (point) is usually somewhere in between the `C %% MODULE %%` and `C %% END MODULE %%`
2. Select the lines between `C %% MODULE %%` and `C %% END MODULE %%` and `replace-string` `%%` with `##`
3. The `C-x C-x`to make the repeat the last selection and run `string-insert-rectangle` and insert the comment text `C~ CPR` -

My Function (I'm new to elisp, bear with my terrible code)

```
(defun comment-pdtn()
  (interactive)
  (set-buffer (buffer-name))                  
  (search-backward "C %% MODULE %%")
  (set-mark (- (point) 14))              ;; 14 is the # of char in C %% MODULE %%
  (search-forward "C %% END MODULE %%")
  (message "begin at %s and ends at %s" ;; Want to ensure that region selection happened
           (region-beginning)
           (region-end))
  (string-insert-rectangle "C~ CPR "))  ;; This isn't working

(comment-pdtn)
```

I'm yet to add the functionality for `replace-string` yet.
How to implement `string-insert-rectangle`in Elisp? I want to write something like this,

1. With region ( string-insert-rectangle "C~ CPR ")
2. With region ( replace-string "%%" "##")

I could do this with macro and save the macro and do away with it, but I want to learn elisp that is the reason behind this question.

Comment: Not to derail the learning, but you probably want to use `M-;` in conjunction with the config `(setq comment-start "C~ CPR " comment-start-skip "C~ CPR +" comment-use-syntax nil)` which could be set in the mode hook for whatever mode this is.

Comment: How did you know this? I was trying to see if I could customize `M-;` but didn't know how. From where can I learn this

Comment: Refer to `C-h i g (emacs)Options for Comments` and the docstrings for the variables in question.

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You usually don't need to manipulate the region with the Lisp code besides accessing the current region, that is, you seldom call `set-mark` from Lisp. Emacs commands operate on the region usually take the arguments `START` and `END`, thus when you call these commands from Lisp, you don't need the region, you need only two buffer positions, for example,

```
M-x mark-whole-buffer
M-x string-insert-rectangle prefix-
```

should be "translated" into

```
(string-insert-rectangle (point-min) (point-max) "prefix-")
```

The following takes advantage of [(emacs) Narrowing](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Narrowing.html), so we don't need to keep tracking the region we're working on.

```
(save-excursion                         ; restore point (optional)
  (save-restriction                     ; undo narrow
    ;; Step 1. Narrow to the region, so we won't change other area by accident
    (narrow-to-region 
     (progn (search-backward "C %% MODULE %%")
            (line-beginning-position))
     (progn (search-forward "C %% END MODULE %%")
            (line-end-position)))

    ;; Step 2. Replace %% with ##, we don't use `replace-string' because its docstring suggests so
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (while (search-forward "%%" nil t)
      (replace-match "##" nil t))

    ;; Step 3. Insert the prefix to each line of the (narrowed) buffer
    (string-insert-rectangle (point-min) (point-max) "C~ CPR ")))
```